# How to make heading fixed and content must scroll on already fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i have a situation where i want to keep **Heading 1** as `fixed` and reset of the `content` must `scroll`

**below image shows them:**

[image]

**below is my current code:**

```css
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 100%;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 210px;
    height: calc(80vh - 6px); /* As you give a border of 3px */
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border: 3px solid red;
    color:white;
}
.stories-preview-wrapper{
  position: fixed;
  height: calc(20vh - 6px); /* As you give a border of 3px */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 3px solid green;
  width: 210px;
}

.header{
    z-index: 100001;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled hidden-xs">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
             <div class="header">
                 <h4>
                    Heading 1
                 </h4>
              </div>
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
      <div class="stories-preview-wrapper">
              <div class="header">
                 <h4>
                    Heading 2
                 </h4>
              </div>
             <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
              </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Add position:fixed; to your header class

Comment: @Shuvo, i have tried you code it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `.header` to be `position: sticky` and remember to set the `top: 0`

Hope this helps! Cheers

```css
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 100%;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 210px;
    height: calc(80vh - 6px); /* As you give a border of 3px */
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border: 3px solid red;
    color:white;
}
.stories-preview-wrapper{
  position: fixed;
  height: calc(20vh - 6px); /* As you give a border of 3px */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 3px solid green;
  width: 210px;
}

.header{
    z-index: 100001;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled hidden-xs">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
             <div class="header">
                 <h4>
                    Heading 1
                 </h4>
              </div>
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                  <li>hello world</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
      <div class="stories-preview-wrapper">
              <div class="header">
                 <h4>
                    Heading 2
                 </h4>
              </div>
             <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
                  <li>hello world 2</li>
              </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your css with the following one:

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 210px;
    height: calc(80vh - 6px); /* As you give a border of 3px */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border: 3px solid red;
    color:white;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Would you please try now? I have updated my code. just replace #sidebar-wrapper css and add .sidebar-nav css. And rest of the css would remain same.